# Variance of absolute value of brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, brownian-motion

Im wondering if anyone has this calculated, I cant seem to find it anywhere online. I am trying to find the variance of absolute value of BM. Here is my attempt:

First, $f_{\lvert W_t \rvert} (x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{ \pi t}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}$

and so:

\begin{align*}
Var(\lvert W_t \rvert) &= E( \lvert W_t \rvert^2) - E( \lvert W_t \rvert)^2\\
 &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}} \int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}} - \left(\sqrt{\frac{2t}{ \pi}} \right)^2 \\
\end{align*}

With @Did 's contribution:
Solving the Integral using integration by parts $(\int u dv = uv=\int vdu)$:

let $u=x~~ du = 1~~ dv=xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}~~v=-te^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}$

Therefore:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}dx=[-txe^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}} \rvert^{\infty}_0 + t \int^{\infty}_0 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}dx
$$
$$
=0 +t \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\sqrt{2\pi t}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}}
$$
$$
=\frac{t}{2} \sqrt{2 \pi t}
$$

Therefore:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}} \int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2t}} - \left(\sqrt{\frac{2t}{ \pi}} \right)^2\\
= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}} \frac{t}{2} \sqrt{2 \pi t} - \frac{2t}{\pi}\\
=t(1-\frac{2}{\pi})
$$

Comment: Because it's the absolute value of a normal distribution.

Comment: The result is $(1-2/\pi)t$, not $2(1-1/\pi)t$, and yes this is probably computed in some lectures introducing the subject. That this is less than $t$ is only natural, to some extent, since $|W_t|$ is less "spread out" than $W_t$.

Comment: @Did Sorry I don't seem to be getting that, I've updated the question to include my working, could you tell me where I went wrong ?

Comment: Your v and dv are wrong.

Comment: @Did oh I completely skipped over that, now im confused then, how do we go about solving this integral, if we choose u to be exponential then the integral becomes harder to solve

Comment: Factor x^2.exp(-x^2/2t) as x.(x.exp(-x^2/2t)) and use the fact that x.exp(-x^2/2t) is the derivative of a multiple of exp(-x^2/2t).

Comment: @Did Got it, that's a great technique